# Particle scaling changing randomly throughout animation render

Tags: animation, particles, scale

Just getting started in Blender and eager to learn so tried following the famous donut tutorial.

After the tutorial I wanted to generate steam raising from the coffee glass so set up a fluid simulation. When trying to render the clip i noticed that the scaling of the previous "Sprinkle" particle system was actively changing after every frame. I had not noticed this problem before as a still frame was used for the final 2 seconds of the rendered animation.

Below is a video of the problem experienced. I have tried setting the scale randomness back to 0 (alas to no effect) and a user suggested "Baking" the icing which resulted in nothing on my end.

Any help or guidance would be deeply appriciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnkDK.jpg